# Отслеживание нажатой кнопки UI Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Возникла такая проблема: В одной сцене Unity есть 4 кнопки (от UI), они находятся в одном канвасе, кнопки выполняют один и тот же метод, а именно переход на следующую сцену. Мне нужно, чтобы в этой следующей сцене дальнейшие действия зависели от того, какую кнопку пользователь нажмет в предыдущей. Каким образом это можно реализовать? Искал в интернете, ничего нужного не нашёл.

Для всех 4 кнопок в Unity задан один и тот же скрипт. Можно ли как-то при выполнении этого скрипта отследить кнопку, которой он был выполнен?

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/440718/) есть про статические классы.

Ну можете использовать PlayerPrefs при завершении одной сцены, и получать данные при загрузке другой.